# Resources located inside META-INF/resources directories in jars in WEB-INF/lib are not found

Tags: tomcat9

I have an application running fine in Tomcat 7 and Tomcat 8. I want to run this application also in Tomcat 9.0.19.

Tomcat 9.0.19 starts correctly with the application deployed. However, when I ask for the start page of the application in the browser, I get a http 404 error for the resource asked for.

Is there additional configuration necessary to get my application running on tomcat 9?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a difference in behavior between tomcat 8 and tomcat 9 concerning JAR scanning.

The keyword tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip in catalina.properties contained jar's with resources in the META-INF/resources directory. In these jars the resources are not discovered any more by tomcat 9. The problem was solved by removing the jars containing a META-INF/resources directory from the list of jarsToSkip in catalina.properties.